# Graphql Nextjs 13:latest error in @apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I want to use mutation function.

apolloProvider.tsx

```
"use client";
// ^ this file needs the "use client" pragma

import { ApolloLink, HttpLink, SuspenseCache } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";

// have a function to create a client for you
function makeClient() {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    // this needs to be an absolute url, as relative urls cannot be used in SSR
    uri: "http://localhost:3000/api",
    // you can disable result caching here if you want to
    // (this does not work if you are rendering your page with `export const dynamic = "force-static"`)
    fetchOptions: { cache: "no-store" },
  });

  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    // use the `NextSSRInMemoryCache`, not the normal `InMemoryCache`
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link:
      typeof window === "undefined"
        ? ApolloLink.from([
            // in a SSR environment, if you use multipart features like
            // @defer, you need to decide how to handle these.
            // This strips all interfaces with a `@defer` directive from your queries.
            new SSRMultipartLink({
              stripDefer: true,
            }),
            httpLink,
          ])
        : httpLink,
  });
}

// also have a function to create a suspense cache
function makeSuspenseCache() {
  return new SuspenseCache();
}

// you need to create a component to wrap your app in
export function ApolloWrapper({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  return (
    <ApolloNextAppProvider
      makeClient={makeClient}
      makeSuspenseCache={makeSuspenseCache}
    >
      {children}
    </ApolloNextAppProvider>
  );
}
```

app/layout.tsx

I want to use mutation in client component in apollo server i don't know how to use @apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support using this package i don't know it how to use mutation using @apollo/client gives me error in latest nextjs app dir

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <ClerkProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={`${roboto.variable} font-inter ${inter.variable}`}>
          <Navbar />
          <Toaster position="top-center" reverseOrder={false} />
          <ApolloWrapper>{children}</ApolloWrapper>
        </body>
      </html>
    </ClerkProvider>
  );
}
```

I want to use Mutation how to use mutation i can use query but not mutation in client and server component how can i?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal `useMutation` hook from the `@apollo/client` package in client components in the browser - it should just work out of the box, even in the app dir.

`@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support` does not have a special version of that, because you would never call a mutation during SSR, so there is no need for extra handling.

If you get any specific error messages, please share those, as just describing it as "error" doesn't help us help you.

Comment: If i am not mistaken (because i am still learning this) you could use a Server Action though in order to mutate your data?

Comment: @ybdiel generally yes, but I'd only recommend that for data that changes very rarely, and to keep any kind of dynamic data in client components. Otherwise you miss out on stuff like optimistic updated and normalized cache updates